# nginx try_files for url redirection script (alias & subfolders conflict)

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to figure how to setup `try_files` to use with my php url redirection script.

The php script work this way:

```
mydomain.com/test
```

Where `test` is an alias which must be treated as the follow:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri = /redirect.php?alias=$request_uri;
}
```

It is working fine here, **test** is sent to `redirect.php` which treats the  **alias** parameter.

But I'm having problem to browse to subfolders as for example `mydomain.com/stats/` -- it does not works.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should add some `location`:

```
location /stats {
  alias /directory/where/stats;
}
```